# How to remove a custom playerView from superView?

Tags: swift, view, avfoundation, avplayer, dismiss

I have a videPlayerView which has ContainerView on top of it to show activityIndicatorView. The view gets loaded when i select an item from a collectionView inside a cell. My question is how to remove this view using the cancelButton, i tried `removeFromSuperview()` for both the container and the playerView but the app crashes with this error

> AQDefaultDevice (1): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0

Here is the code:

```
class VideoPlayerView: UIView {
    var videoUrl: String!
    var uuidd: String!


    let activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let aiv = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
        aiv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        aiv.startAnimating()

        return aiv
    }()



    lazy var controlsContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1)
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlezoomout)))

        return view
    }()

    func handlezoomout(hh: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("n3me")


}


    lazy var cancelButton: UIButton = {
        let cancelButton = UIButton()
        cancelButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cancel"), for: UIControlState())
        cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancel), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cancelButton
    }()

    func cancel() {

        controlsContainerView.removeFromSuperview()
        let video = VideoPlayerView()
        video.removeFromSuperview()


    }







    lazy var pausePlayButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        let image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        button.setImage(image, for: UIControlState())
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.isHidden = true

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePause), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()


    var isPlaying = false

    func handlePause() {
        if isPlaying {
            player?.pause()
            pausePlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: UIControlState())
        } else {
            player?.play()
            pausePlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), for: UIControlState())
        }

        isPlaying = !isPlaying
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)



        setUpPlayerView()

      controlsContainerView.frame = frame
      addSubview(controlsContainerView)



        cancelButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16.0, y: 20.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
        controlsContainerView.addSubview(cancelButton)


        controlsContainerView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
        activityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        activityIndicatorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        controlsContainerView.addSubview(pausePlayButton)
        pausePlayButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        pausePlayButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        pausePlayButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        pausePlayButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black



    }




    var player: AVPlayer?

    fileprivate func setUpPlayerView() {

    let postQuery = PFQuery(className: "posts")
    postQuery.whereKey("uuid", equalTo: PostUuidGlobalVariable.postuuid.last!)
    postQuery.getFirstObjectInBackground { (object, error) in
    if (error == nil && object != nil) {
    let videoFile = object!["video"] as! PFFile

    if let url = URL (string: videoFile.url!) {
     self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
    self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    playerLayer.frame = self.frame





    self.player?.play()
        self.player?.isMuted = false

    self.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)


    }
    }
    }
    }




    func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {




    }



    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        //this is when the player is ready and rendering frames
        if keyPath == "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" {
            activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()


            pausePlayButton.isHidden = false
            isPlaying = true
        }
    }




    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


class VideoLauncher: NSObject {




    func showVideoPlayer() {

        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            view.frame = CGRect(x: keyWindow.frame.width - 10, y: keyWindow.frame.height - 10, width: 10, height: 10)




            let height = keyWindow.frame.height
            let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: height)


            let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)



            view.addSubview(videoPlayerView)




            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                view.frame = keyWindow.frame

            }, completion: { (completedAnimation) in

                //maybe we'll do something here later...





                UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
            })

            keyWindow.addSubview(view)




        }



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance this is related to you changing the user interface outside of the main thread.

From UIView documents
 
**'Threading Considerations

Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the 
UIView
 class from code running in the main thread of your application. The only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view object itself, but all other manipulations should occur on the main thread.'**

Also your cancel function creates a new video player view and then tries to remove it from it parent which doesn't look correct.

Your cancel callback should probably be as follows

```
func cancel() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        // to remove controls
        self.controlsContainerView.removeFromSuperview()

        // to remove video player view
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Spads. I get a complier error for self.view (Value of type VideoplayerView has no member View. I tried to remove the VideoplayerView directly but i got the error.  terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Yeah the 'view' was a typo. You should probably manage the visibility of the VideoPlayerView from a ViewController not the view itself. The crash is most likely due to you removing the view while running code inside it.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. I ended up implementing UIPanGesturerecognizer like the one on youtube and it finally works now. Thanks.